# How to make a class deserialize as a different name

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xmlserializer

for instance something like:

```
<apple />
```

will serialize just fine to a class called "apple". however, if I want to call that class "Dragon" it will not serialize (which makes sense). I want to know how to mark up "Dragon" such that when the XmlSerializer sees it, it knows that "Dragon" is the same as

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming `Dragon` defines at least a superset of the properties and fields that `apple` does then competent_tech's answer is appropriate though I think your question is actually asking about:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlType("apple")]
public class Dragon
```

If `Dragon` is *not* compatible with `apple` then you may be better off performing an explicit conversion between the types. Assuming your application knows the definition of both `apple` and `Dragon`, this can be accomplished by deserializing your `apple` stream to an `apple` object, mapping the properties to a new `Dragon` object, and then serializing your `Dragon` object.

Answer (score 5):

You would want to add the [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmltypeattribute.aspx) to the class.

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlType("Dragon")]
public class apple
```